# Kotlin Javascript -library-files invalid argument

Tags: kotlin

Following instruction here:
   https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line-library-js.html
but getting **Invalid argument: -library-files** when compiling. I am not sure where I did wrong. Any help appreciated.

Compiler obtained from https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.1

kotlin-compiler-1.1.zip

```
kotlinc-js -output binom.js -library-files sample-library.jar binom.kt

Invalid argument: -library-files
Usage: kotlinc-js <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -output <path>             Output file path
  -no-stdlib                 Don't use bundled Kotlin stdlib
  -libraries <path>          Paths to Kotlin libraries with .meta.js and .kjsm files, separated by system file separator
  -source-map                Generate source map
  -meta-info                 Generate .meta.js and .kjsm files with metadata. Use to create a library
  -target { v5 }             Generate JS files for specific ECMA version
  -module-kind { plain, amd, commonjs, umd }
                         Kind of a module generated by compiler
  -main {call,noCall}        Whether a main function should be called
  -output-prefix <path>      Path to file which will be added to the beginning of output file
  -output-postfix <path>     Path to file which will be added to the end of output file
  -language-version <version> Provide source compatibility with specified language version
  -api-version <version>     Allow to use declarations only from the specified version of bundled libraries
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Enable verbose logging output
  -version                   Display compiler version
  -help (-h)                 Print a synopsis of standard options
  -X                         Print a synopsis of advanced options
  -P plugin:<pluginId>:<optionName>=<value>
                         Pass an option to a plugin
```

Answer (score 3):

This option has been renamed to `-libraries` before JavaScript support has been released as a part of Kotlin 1.1. This part of the tutorial is not up-to-date yet, I'll fix it.

Comment: Now get error with binom.kt: binom.kt:8:16: error: unresolved reference: forOdd
        (1..n).forOdd { result = result * it }
               ^
binom.kt:8:43: error: unresolved reference: it
        (1..n).forOdd { result = result * it }